# Programmatically create Redirects in Wagtail

Tags: django, redirect, wagtail

Is there a way to programmatically create functioning `Redirect` objects in Wagtail?

I am trying the obvious (naively creating the object):

`Redirect.objects.create(old_path='/test', redirect_link='https://stackoverflow.com')`

This creates a `Redirect` that is visible in the Wagtail admin panel, however navigating to `/test` simply 404s without redirecting.

**However, if I then save the `Redirect` from the admin panel, it suddenly works.**

Is there some special post-save logic I need to run in order to activate the redirect? I looked through the source and could not find anything.

Comment: Your example code works fine when I try it. There is some cleanup code mainly to deal with missing/extra slashes (normalise_path, https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/redirects/models.py#L55) which *won't* get called automatically when you create it through `Redirects.object.create` - perhaps when you tried it, you used a value for `old_path` that wasn't valid until that cleanup was applied?

Comment: Thanks. I tried my code again and strangely, it's working. I think I may have been running into DNS caching issues when I was testing originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error - I believe I was running into DNS caching issues that prevented the redirect from working. My original code seems to work fine now.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the exact same code as part of django testing does _not_ work, you get that django resolver 404 error, so just user error doesn't feel like it covers it

Comment: Have you tried creating redirects with and without trailing slashes? Depending on your Django config, this could be the reason why. My programmatic redirects did not work if they contained a trailing slash.